# PHP/mysql Missing Row on query

Tags: php, mysql

I am running the following query in a PHP script:

```
$radius_query = "SELECT zip, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(" . $latitude .") ) * cos(         radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( lng ) - radians( " . $longitude . ") ) + sin( radians(" .     $latitude .") ) * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) AS distance 
FROM ZIP HAVING distance < ". $radius;
$radius_result = $db_zipcode->query($radius_query);


if (!$radius_result){
   echo 'Could not run query: ' . mysql_error();
   exit;
   }

$row = $radius_result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    While($row = $radius_result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
     $zip[] = $row['zip'];
}


foreach ($zip as $zip_display){
echo $zip_display . ",  " . '';
}
```

The query itself works with one minor error - it does not return the first row of data.  It should return a list of zip codes similar to this:

40324, 40339, 40340, 40347, 40356...

This is the result I get when I run the same query in phpMyAdmin.

However when I run the query above in a PHP script, the result set starts with 40339, and then includes all the remaining zip codes.  Its not a mileage issue (i.e. the missing zip is well within the radius - as it shows up when I run the query in phpMyAdmin).

What am I doing wrong in the PHP query to miss that first row of data?  Its not just a display problem because when I insert the query results in a DB, it is also missing the first row.

Thanks!

Comment: u are getting `40339` in your list , so maybe is the order or?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is in the first `fetch`, they take your first row...
Run this without 
`$row = $radius_result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);`
I had the same problem about a day ago.

Comment: Thanks to all the quick responses - eliminating the first fetch worked.

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to do an implicit loop in the PHP, try

```
$zip = $radius_result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Comment: To amplify a bit - the exact error in your code is that `fetch()` is being called an extra time before the loop starts. Using fetchAll() is better.

Comment: You don't need to run a loop with `->fetch` and build your own array. `fetchAll` can do that for you, more efficiently.